# Blue Card additional sheet restrictions - employer name

Tags: working-visas, germany, blue-card

I am a non-EU citizen currently working in Germany as a software engineer.
I entered Germany with an entry visa on which it says "Blaue Karte" and my employer name, and that happened in February.
I only got my *Aufenthaltstitel* this week. 
On the *Zusatzblatt* I can see the following:

*"Beschäftigung nicht erlaubt mit Ausnahme der Tätigkeit als Software Engineer
Selbstständige Tätigkeit erlaubt
Nach 2jähr. versicherungspfl. Beschäftig. ist Beschäftig. jeder Art erlaubt."*

I don't see my employer name in there. Does that mean I can switch jobs without seeking an approval from the foreigners agency, as long as the new job satisfies the Blue Card requirements, and my position stays the same, that is, as long as the job itself is in the same field and payed above Blue Card limit?

Of course, I am aware that I have to notify them - but to be precise, does that mean I can start working on my job immediately after informing them?

Comment: any update on this , do you need to wait till you get a reply from them or just notifying them with a new contract is fine.My Zusatzblatt doesnt have a company name on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can officially confirm that this is possible.
Of course, under the condition that new job is in the same field and that the salary is still high enough for a Blue Card.

If your employer name is not written on your *Zusatzblatt*, your Blue Card is not tied to them. 
This confirmation I got from the foreigners agency directly. 
What you do need to do is notify them.

Comment: any update on this , do you need to wait till you get a reply from them or just notifying them with a new contract is fine.My Zusatzblatt doesnt have a company name on it